# How to retrieve object from database to put as foreign key

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys

In my database, I have table "User" and "Role" and I search to put a role in a user when the user sign up. The problem is that when I retrieve the role from database and post the user, a new role is create and I don't want it. I want the a existing role are put as foreign key.

Comment: What Database are you using, MySQL? And are you using any plain SQL-Queries to insert the new user or do you use something like JPA to handle all database queries? Maybe you could show us the part of your code where you create the new user?

Comment: No need for being sorry by the way, as long as you try to write a decent question and respect some formatting rules, no one will mock about - most of us (including me) are probably no native English people.

Comment: Please create **good** tags for your question! (Java-ee is **not** good)

Answer (score 0):

In JPA you don't think as *foreign keys*. What you model is an Object which can have relations to other objects, such as a class `User` may have a list of `Role` references.

You'd then annotate it with the according JPA annotations to map this relation to your database tables. You may check the [Oracle Java EE tutorial on JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm) to learn how to do that.

Then, when putting a new Object (meaning one with a new ID) into the list, it will result in getting a new entry in the referring table when persisting it.